# Change tab content with dropdown value?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, forms, adminform, tabs

I'm building a module, where the user can fill his homepage with blocks from the backend. 
All blocks are taken in an admin grid ui compontent, and there's 3 different kinds of blocks to choose from: 1. Images 2. Sliders 3. Text

Of course every block needs it's own editing form in the admin, which leads me to my problem. The editing form of a block is based on two tabs: info and content. At the info tab, you would choose the form of content you want, which then should update the form on the content tab to suit your needs (either an image upload, or multiple for a slider, or just some text with a button).

Below is an image of the form i'm referring too, the content dropdown should change the form on the content tab.

Any advice is appreciated!

[image: admin form]